# How to I get selected rows in an table?

Tags: jquery

I have a table where each rows has a check box.

This code works for another table:

```
    jQuery('#my_table_id tr').has(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
      request_arr[i] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      i++;
    });
```

Now in this case, I have a table object:

```
    var tbl = $('#my_table') // In my code, this is done dynamically

    // This does not work
    jQuery(tbl + 'tr').has(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
      request_arr[i] = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      i++;
    });
```

How can I get checked rows using a table object like `tbl`?
I've tried various drilldowns, but I can't get any to work.

**Update**

This is how I've set up my html:

```
<table id="t1"></table>

<div class="bulk_action">
  <div title="Remove requests" class="trash_iconset_grey_16px removeRequest"></div>
  <div title="some other button" class="abc"></div>
</div>

<table id="t2"></table>

<div class="bulk_action">
  <div title="Remove requests" class="trash_iconset_grey_16px removeRequest"></div>
  <div title="some other button" class="abc"></div>
</div>
```

Clicking the "button" below table 1, will set `tbl = <table id="t1">`.

@elcanrs solution will also fetch checked rows in table nr 2. I only want checked rows for table nr 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery(tbl + 'tr')` is the same as `$($('#my_table') + 'tr')` which makes no sense. Do this instead:

```
tbl.find('tr')
```

Comment: right - `jQuery('tr', tbl)` will work to - using tbl as a context for the selection.

Comment: @elcanrs I've tried that before and it works... but, the problem is that I have another table below my first table. If I check some checkboxes in that table as well, then this is included in my `find - each`. I need to find checked rows in `tbl` only.

Comment: @Steven: Then there is something wrong with your structure. `find` will only find descendants of the selected elements.

Comment: `#my_table` is a unique element, hence the id, so no other tables will be modified...

Comment: You can see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AK57r/1/ I get the same result. Tables have different ID's

Comment: I found the problem. Array was not reset inside the flick function. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be `jQuery(tbl + ' tr')` to account for the space between the table id and `tr`?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(tbl + ' tr')
```

is incorrect, because you are trying to combine an object with a string.
you should use the find method to look for the checked checkbox, then move up to the first tr tag. try using:

```
tbl.find(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(...);
```